# How to check if my string matches an array element in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, if-statement, enums

My `if` condition is:

```
if str == STATUSES.done {
```

What should be the `if` condition? This is pseudocode:

```
STATUSES = %w (
   in_progress
   done
   request_incomplete
)

var str = 'done'
```

I'm checking only against `STATUSES.done` and not for any other value. 
So, `if STATUSES.include?(str)` won't work.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We can't work with pseudo-code, we need to see your actual attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `STATUSES` is an array, find the first element that matches `done` and compare:

```
done_status = STATUSES.detect { |status| status == 'done' } 
if str == done_status 
  # do something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, i think you should use enum.

In ruby, if you working with `status` of object i think you should use [`enum`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

This is very useful.
You can declare your class like:

```
class YourClass
  enum status: { in_progress: 0, done: 1, request_incomplete: 2 }
end
```

- when you want checking object class_x initialized from `YourClass`, you can check status you can call likely: `class_x.status`
- or when you want check class_x is in progress or not, you can use: `class_x.in_progress?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class MyClass
  STATUSES = [
    IN_PROGRESS = 'in_progress',
    DONE = 'done',
    REQUEST_INCOMPLETE = 'request_incomplete'
  ]
end
```

Check status by:

```
str = 'done'
str == MyClass::DONE # true
```

Access the array:

```
MyClass::STATUSES # ["in_progress", "done", "request_incomplete"]
```

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it.